# Why isn't bitand properly parsed to form an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, token, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference

An rvalue reference could be formed using an alternative token:

```
int and i = 0;
```

It could also be formed after splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines:

```
int &\
& i = 0;
```

**So why doesn't the following program compile?**

```
int main() {
    int &\
bitand i = 5;
}
```

Based on the standard, I don't see why it shouldn't.

> **[lex.digraph]** In all respects of the language, each alternative token
>   behaves the same, respectively, as its primary token, except for its
>   spelling.
>
> **[lex.phases]** Each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately
>   followed by a new-line character is deleted,  splicing physical source
>   lines to form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any
>   physical source line shall be eligible for being part of such a
>   splice.

Is there additional information that I missed, or is this a compiler bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backslash+newline sequence is a red herring. These things are removed before the tokenization phase (that's phase two and phase three of the translation, respectively). We can thus concentrate on these fragments instead:

```
&&
&bitand
```

The first line has one token, `&&`. The second line has two tokens, `&` and `bitand`. The last token is equivalent to `&` so the second line behaves exactly as if it contained two `&` tokens. This is different from one `&&` token. The latter is composed of two `&` characters, not two `&` tokens.